How do you map bond RepFlows into forward swap RepFlows?
RepFlows
Practically speaking, a RepFlow is a vectorised representation of the cash flows from investing in a cash instrument that can be used for modelling.
For example, an investment of £1 today (10th Sep 2024) in a bond expiring on 22nd October 2025, with a 3.5% semi-annual coupon, and a price of par might have a RepFlow like the following:



Cash Flow Date
RepFlow




Today
-1


22-Oct-2024
+0.0175


22-Apr-2024
+0.0175


22-Oct-2025
+1



For what it's worth, I am referring specifically here to the 3.5% 2025 Gilt.
Mapping RepFlows onto swap forwards
Depending on what someone is trying to do, they might want to map this set of RepFlows into a different space, such as a set of swap forward dates. This might be referred to as MappedRepFlows.
Since we are using a Gilt as an example, let's consider the Bank of England meeting dates as our set of swap forwards, as of today:



Fwd Start
Fwd End
MappedRepFlow




Today
19-Sep-2024
?


19-Sep-2024
07-Nov-2024
?


07-Nov-2024
19-Dec-2024
?


19-Dec-2024
06-Feb-2025
?


06-Feb-2025
20-Mar-2025
?


20-Mar-2025
08-May-2025
?


08-May-2025
19-Jun-2025
?


19-Jun-2025
07-Aug-2025
?


07-Aug-2025
18-Sep-2025
?


18-Sep-2025
06-Nov-2025
?


06-Nov-2025
17-Dec-2025
0



The challenge
So I am trying to think of a sensible rule to fill in the gaps in the above table in such a way that they are representative of the RepFlows for the bond, but sitting in swap forward space instead. Assume knowledge of live bond yields/market prices, swap discount curves for the currency in question etc.
Is there a generally accepted way that this is done within academia?
If not, are there any interesting rules that you can think of, or have used in the past, to achieve this?

The obvious way seems to allocate the cashflow to the bucket that aligns with the same dates and setting all other buckets as zero. The fact you have not suggested this trivial answer suggests your designs for a such a process have to have some other physical meaning. If you are looking for a risk based approach of course that is possible too but it would not be consistent with the presentation of your original "RepFlows", so without further context I'm afraid I can't help.
